# How to conditionally add a prop value if a boolean state value is true

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a ring to a button if the addButtonRing state value is true. I am using react, typescript and tailwind.

```
const [addButtonRing, setAddButtonRing] = useState(false);

<button
className={ addButtonRing?`ring-black`:`ring-white` `rounded-xl shadow-md`}>
Button Text
</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the trouble?

Comment: @AlexRintt I am getting an error with this code

Comment: Then show us the error.

Comment: @AlexRintt left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects. This is the error from the answer posted

Answer (score 0):

```
className={ 
  `rounded-xl shadow-md`,
  (addButtonRing ? `ring-black` : `ring-white`)
}
```

There you go.
Firstly, you missed the comma between 2 strings (classes).

Secondly add paranthesis for ternary operation so that it'll be easy to understand where condition is ending.

Now just toggle the button and you'll see the classes changing. Add this to your button:

```
onClick={() => setAddButtonRing(!addButtonRing)}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hesan , however im getting the following errors with this:Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.ts(2695)
JSX expressions may not use the comma operator. Did you mean to write an array?ts(18007)

Answer (score 0):

When writing a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you need to interpolate your variable using the `${...}` notation, like this:

```
<button
  className={`${addButtonRing ? "ring-black" : "ring-white"} rounded-xl shadow-md`}
>
  Button Text
</button>
```